Publishing and Auto-update apps uisng SFTP in VB.net
Visual Studio 2022, has a feature in VB.NET applications to publish the app using FTP.
but nowadays FTP and HTTP protocols are not supported by many providers due to their lack of security.
is there any way to use SFTP and HTTPS for such reason?
I need my program to check for updates daily and update automatically as needed. I know the VISUAL STUDIO 2022 has such a feature to check for updates in defined intervals but I don't know how to use it.

What type of application here? Are you talking about a web publish? You can always publish to a local folder, and then use any FTP system, including the built in one from windows (use the windows file explorer, turn on the address bar, and type in FTP from that).  The automatic updating and publish? That is a Mount Everest of a separate issue, and automatic publishing and updating of web sites was never supported from VS anyway. I suppose you could write a batch file or windows script that copies the published folder to the server, and then use the task scheduler to run that script daily.

@AlbertD.Kallal
, I know about manual publishing on the local folder and the transfer via FTP. but in the VS2022 publish option there is an automatic FTP publish and update method. also, there is an automatic check for the update method in VS project options.
my question is to know how I can use them and how I can use more secure protocols like SFTP and HTTPS with these methods.

Hum, not aware of some "check for update" in vs2022, and that it had/has anything to do with automatic web publishing. I ONLY suggested folder publish if you going to setup some windows script that is scheduled to automatic this process on a daily basis. If you don't have FTP/FTPS enabled, then of course that option is off the table. You could consider installing the Web deploy to the web server, and then you don't need FTP/FTPS. However, this does mean that an additional port and server is now running on the web server, and thus you can publish using "Web deploy".

In all of these cases and all of the publish options in vs2022, none to my knowledge are "automatic" and thus don't occur without use of the publish option.  So, some semantics is at play here in regards to using the term "automatic". There is no such automatic publishing without you using the publish option from VS, and I not aware that "check for updates" has anything to do with publishing, unless this is some new fangled option in vs2022 exists. So, if you don't want to use FTP/FTPS, then you can use "web deploy", but that assumes you can install web deploy on the hosted server.

We don't have FTP enabled, and we did not want to risk having "web deploy" installed on the IIS server for reasons of security. In fact, we don't even have remote desktop enabled either. So, the only way we can get to our server running IIS is though Hyper-V and using "connect".  We went down this road for reasons of security, and we did not want FTP/FTPS, nor web deploy nor remote desktop enabled for that server. (its a separate server in a DMZ and not part of the company domain and network). So, automatic scheduled publishing is not any option I'm aware of in vs2022.

To me you seem to mix two things – publishing your binaries (from development machine) – and checking for updates and actually updating your application (from user's machine). – Those two only tangentially related.

Currently,  SFTP publish option is not supported in Visual Studio.
Please vote  the relevant thread to attract Microsoft's attention:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Option-for-publishing-websites-to-SFTP-l/635083
